# How to make HTML Anchor link to do 2 different things?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make an anchor do two things,

1. Bring the user down the same page
2. Open a new tab to another link.

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com/#test" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com'); window.open('http://www.example.com');">TEST</a>
```

Comment: Does the first request means that you want to reload the same page or you want to scroll down? Can you elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by having two events in one single element, e.g:

```js
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",function(){
            window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', '_self');
            window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');


        })
```

```html
<a id="test">click me</a>
```

So the first link will open in the same page, and the other one will open on a blank new page.

Answer (score 0):

you can control your link behaviour by adding listener on it and prevent default action, example:

```
const link = document.querySelector("a"); // it would be good to add some id to your html anchor tag
const url = "http://www.example.com/#BINANCVIDEO"; // tab url you want to open
    link.addEventListener("click", event => {
      event.preventDefault(); // stop default redirect 
      window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); // scroll user to bottom
      window.open(url, '_blank'); // you can add .focus() to this line if you prefer that
    });
```